# Stop wget but allow convert-links

Tags: unix, process, wget, posix

I'm running a wget command with a rather deep recursion depth. The deep recursion depth is needed to get the files I want, but I don't want to wait for the operation to complete. I see that I can terminate wget through a number of channels (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, kill, *etc*.). The problem is that if I use one of these "forceful" ways to terminate wget, the effects of `-k` (convert links) are unnoticed.

How can I terminate wget while forcing (allowing, encouraging, permitting) it to convert links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after looking up I did not find an specific solution. However, a workaround can work if you are downloading multiple files.

One way to stop your download in the middle and still converting links is to use the `-Q` option. So you can set a quota and as soon as it reaches the size it will finish the last file, and starting converting. But, you have to download multiple files to Quota works.

I.e.:

```
wget -k -r -Q150K http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/
```

So, the -r option download the page recursively (to get multiple files) until get 150KB, then it starts linking whatever was downloaded.

Comment: It looks like this is as close as I will get, thanks!